# SQL GROUP BY choose row with highest date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of match participants, where each entry has player, team, and date fields. I want to make a list of all players and their corresponding teams, so I do something like

```
SELECT player, COUNT(DISTINCT matchid) matches, team FROM participants GROUP BY player
```

However, if a player switched teams, it will return a random(?) team for that player. Is there any way to make it choose the entry corresponding to the highest `date` field (so it returns the current team)? I tried replacing `participants` with `(SELECT * FROM participants ORDER BY date DESC) x` but it doesn't seem to affect anything at all.

So far all I can think of is using `MID(MAX(CONCAT(date, '_', team)),12)` but it assumes that `date` is always a 10 digit number, which might or might not be the case.

---

Here's an example data

```
MATCHID       PLAYER               TEAM               DATE
1             Bob                  Team A             1234567890
1             John                 Team A             1234567890
1             James                Team B             1234567890
1             Ross                 Team B             1234567890
2             James                Team A             1234567891
2             John                 Team A             1234567891
2             Bob                  Team B             1234567891
2             Ross                 Team B             1234567891
```

Which indicates that a match was played between Team A (consisting of Bob and John) and Team B (consisting of James and Ross) at 1234567890. Then, Bob and James switched teams and played another match at a later date. I would like to receive data like the following

```
PLAYER               TEAM               MATCHES
Bob                  Team B             2
John                 Team A             2
James                Team A             2
Ross                 Team B             2
```

However, there seems to be no way to guarantee that Bob and James entries will show the correct teams.

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result

Comment: I don't think I can include tables in posts?

Comment: please check this link to see how you can improve the question..https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I think the question is pretty straightforward so I don't see how that would help but I added an example of what I'm trying to do anyway.

Comment: @riv this helps a lot, because ppl can easily create sample data to test their solutions. But `matchid` is missing in your sample data.

Comment: Oh, I thought it could be some special form of MAX that I can't find (select field X with the highest value of Y). Otherwise the MAX(CONCAT) seems to work if I know the exact length of `date`. I'm not sure how it affects the performance, but my table is pretty small for now so it shouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Did any of the answers suit your needs? Could you accept one or leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution: I just replaced the `team` column with a corelated subquery, which selects the first team ordered by `date DESC`.

```sql
SELECT player, COUNT(DISTINCT matchid) matches, (
  SELECT team 
  FROM participants p2
  WHERE p2.player = p1.player
  ORDER BY `date` DESC
  LIMIT 1
) as team
FROM participants p1
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY team, player;;
```

Another solution with a JOIN ON MAX(`DATE`):

```sql
SELECT plr.player, plr.matches, prt.team
FROM (
  SELECT player, COUNT(DISTINCT matchid) matches, MAX(`date`) as last_played
  FROM participants
  GROUP BY player
) plr
JOIN participants prt 
    ON  prt.player = plr.player
    AND prt.`date` = plr.last_played
ORDER BY prt.team, plr.player;
```

Using MAX(CONCAT()):

```sql
SELECT player, COUNT(DISTINCT matchid) matches,
  SUBSTR(MAX(CONCAT(LPAD(`DATE`, 10, 0), team)), 11) as team
FROM participants p1
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY team, player;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98f2f5/16

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the first team out of a `group_concat`:

```
SELECT   player,
         COUNT(DISTINCT matchid) matches,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(team ORDER BY date DESC SEPARATOR ','),',',1) team 
FROM     participants
GROUP BY player
```

See [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/228fd/1).